# backface visibility not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am making a book that opens the cover on click. However, for some reason, the back side of the front page doesn't show up in IE. It does work in firefox and chrome. I have tried many things, but I haven't found a solution.

**Here is the link to it on codepen.**
http://codepen.io/modDesigns/pen/LVwpWW

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="left">
    <div class="l-front">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="text-center frontTitle">Click to open Book</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="l-back">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="tops">
                    <img src="http://theaudiophilegroup.ky/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/person-icon.png" class="img-responsive avatar" width="25" height="25" />
                    <h3 class="mywords"><strong>Sokratus<trong></h3></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="title addPadding"><strong>Make me your mentor</strong></h1>
                <p class="pad">Like everyday, I was reaching towards my ‘inbox zero’ goal and I found this newsletter from 99u.com. It had this story titled ‘This is why you don’t have a mentor’. I could easily relate to that title. So I was going through the article and suddenly it hit me, what if I don’t seek out for mentors? What if I offer mentorship from my side? Sure I’m relatively new in this business but there are bunch of people who are just starting out. I remember my early days when I clearly did not have sense of... almost anything.</p>
                <p class="pad">Read more ></p>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="diag">
        </dvi>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the transforms work correctly in IE11, you have to animate the back and front sides independently (in opposite directions), not the whole container.

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
.l-front, .l-back {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden; 
}

.l-front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.l-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform-origin: right 0;
  left: -100%;
}

.open .l-front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.open .l-back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Your JS can also be massively simplified, you just need to toggle the "open" class on your container:

```
$('.left').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

Updated codepen is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGvqXj

I have also tidied up some unnecessary styles from your CSS.

**Update, 5th Sep 2017**

This no longer works in newer versions of IE11 (from 11.0.29 on) as a bug in the handling of `backface-visibility` was introduced which MS do not plan to fix. :(
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/2474735

Comment: Cool glad it works for you! I did notice that the transform looks very "3D" in other browsers, but flat in IE... I expect there's a way to make them the same but I'm not 100% sure how.

Comment: Thats okay, I will try to make the 3D look more realistic in IE. But otherwise, I love it! Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Hm.. this example doesn't work for me in IE 11. No animation visible. When clicked to open the book the cover disappers and after a time, the page appers. But it's not visible during the animation.

Comment: Hey @MikeKeskinov, you're right - it no longer works for me either!
When I wrote the answer 2 years ago I was on a Win7 PC, and now that I have a new one with Win 10 I think something's changed in IE11 (it works in Edge)... A quick search around seems to suggest others are having problems with 2D transforms on Win10/IE11. I'll see if I can update the answer with a fix.

Comment: Seems like there is a known issues with `backface-visibility` in newer builds of IE11. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/2474735
MS not planning to fix it as it's not broken in Edge!

Comment: I was not able to find any easy fix. Now, we just don't support the animation for IE. As it was said, it works in Edge and any other "normal" browsers. For IE I just wrote the fix which disable 3D animation all together. Sorry, IE users....